# Django App with Tinder script deployed on Heroku (Selenium + Chromedriver) need guidance

Tags: python, django, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

**Has anyone had experience deploying a Django app on Heroku that contains a script within it?**

I'm currently building a web app that works as a front end tool to a couple of python bots that I have been creating during the years, as well as for personal useful tools (Scripts). The issue is that I've been trying to deploy my app on Heroku and test the functionality of running my Tinder Bot from within Heroku, but I have not been successful, i'm currently getting errors such as:

"unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"

Thing's that I've done to try to solve the issue:

1- Setting the chrome arguments as:

```
chrome_settings = Options()
chrome_settings.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_settings.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_settings.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
```

As well as setting the directories for chrome binary and chromedriver to:

```
GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome'
path_of_chrome_driver = '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'
```

But I am still getting the same error. **Would anyone know whats the proper procedure to create a web app that can contain python scripts in it, and to be deployed on Heroku?**

Ps: I have followed the steps to set up (Whitenoise and gunicorn) for heroku deployment.

Requirements:

`Django==2.1.1`
`gunicorn==19.9.0`
`pytz==2018.5`
`selenium==3.14.1`
`urllib3==1.23`
`whitenoise==4.1`

This is the site I am developing: https://bot-tools-collection.herokuapp.com/

**Update**

Link to the code:

https://gist.github.com/keithlowc/d0b274005ecf9d41b4f087620b487dc5

Comment: Are you using the [chromedriver buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver), and an appropriate browser buildpack?

Comment: Instead of chunks can publish your driver initialization code block in full?

Comment: @Chris yes i have installed google chrome and chromedriver buildpacks

Comment: @Newcontributor my code is here: https://gist.github.com/keithlowc/d0b274005ecf9d41b4f087620b487dc5

Comment: @keithlow did you manage to find a solution? Stuck at similar place

Comment: @mking Hey I did not complete this project - Though, I think heroku itself doesn't support selenium. And, probably we would need to use something like Kubernetes to run this kind of scripts. Let me know if you find a solution! :)